# Node.js: Sequential execution of asynchronous tasks

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, q

I have an array of objects similar to:

```
let builds = [
    { status: "Failed"},
    { status: "Completed"},
    { status: "Building"},
    { status: "Building"},
    { status: "Failed"},
    { status: "Cancelled"},
   ...
]
```

The number of elements will vary and the `status` of each would also vary, with a minimum array size of zero.

I need to write a function that would:

- Iterate through the array to and look for any items with a `status` of `Building`
- Update the `status` of those items to `Cancelled`
- When there are no more occurrences of `Building`, push a new item in the array similar to: `{ status: "Building" }`

The catch is that the array is stored in a MongoDB and hence each operation needs to be persisted to the DB in an asynchronous fashion.  I am using Q promises for everything.

My attempt at doing this looks like this at the moment:

```
let count=0;  // Keep track of how many "builds" in "Building" state

module.getAllBuilds((builds) => {
    builds.forEach((build) => {
        if (build.status == "Building") {
             count++;
             module.cancelBuild(build)
             .then(() => {
                 if (!--count) {  // When counter is zero, all builds have been dealt with.
                     module.newBuild();
                     return;
                 }
              })
        }
     })
     module.newBuild();   // Get here if the build array is empty or no builds in "Building" state
})
```

I am using a `count` variable to track the number of entries in the `Building` status, much like a stack.  When the stack is empty, then I proceed with creating the new build.

The trouble is that I have to call the `module.newBuild()` in one of two places depending whether or not any builds were in `Building` state.

Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: I take it you understand your code is performing the asynch tasks "sequentially"?

Comment: Yep, the intention is to execute it sequentially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By first filtering the builds Array for just the "Building"s - then using `Array#reduce`, you can simplify your code as follows

```
module.getAllBuilds((builds) => builds.filter(build => build.status == 'Building').reduce((promise, build) => promise.then(()=> module.cancelBuild(build)), Promise.resolve())
.then(() => module.newBuild()))
```

or, trying to make it more readable (and failing) :p

```
module.getAllBuilds((builds) => 
    builds.filter(build => build.status == 'Building')
    .reduce(
        (promise, build) => promise.then(() => module.cancelBuild(build)), 
        Promise.resolve()
    )
.then(() => module.newBuild()))
```

Or the transpiled ES5 version

```
module.getAllBuilds(function (builds) {
    return builds.filter(function (build) {
        return build.status == 'Building';
    }).reduce(function (promise, build) {
        return promise.then(function () {
            return module.cancelBuild(build);
        });
    }, Promise.resolve()).then(function () {
        return module.newBuild();
    });
});
```

Note: the `module.newBuild()` will get called even if there are no "Building" in `builds`

Comment: The indentation of the `reduce` arguments in the first snippet freaks me out…

Comment: Yeah, me too - the whole code was originally two lines, and I tried to make it more readable and failed :p if you have an idea on how to better "format" it, please feel free to edit @Bergi

Comment: Wow, that's deep.  It certainly ticks the "short & concise" box.  I'm not 100% clear on how you're using reduce().  I get using filter() first, and the args to reduce(), but the body of reduce() is a bit of voodoo.  Is "Promise.resolve()" being returned for the next iteration?

Comment: reduce is a common way to take an array and more or less turn it into a promise chain

Comment: I just made it even more concise, because I realised you don't need the `results` of all the `module.cancelBuild` promises

Comment: Surprisingly more readable now that it's even shorter :)   So you're using reduce() to effectively create a promise chain.  Each iteration of reduce() would call cancelBuild() then the then() of that skips over to the next "build"?  And if there no items at all, would the final then() be invoked?  ie: if the array of builds is empty, would a promise be created?

Comment: Yes, it should perform regardless of how many items in the (resulting) array

Comment: Brilliant, I'm just testing it out.  Will let you know shortly